# Is subspace a "real" theory?

Tags: spacetime

Is subspace based on a real theory? Did Einstein ever have any thoughts or theorems about it? If so, whas was the theory, did it have any thing to do with general relativity? If it was not Einstein, who came up with it?

Comment: Assuming you mean *subspace* as used by generations of science fiction authors then the answer is no. There is no detached extra dimension that you can move into, travel at superlight speed, then move back into *normal* space.

Comment: Has anyone tried to model a detached or attached extra dimension and shown how it doesn't add up and nothing would make sense?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Please clarify with a link or reference what particular meaning of [subspace](http://www.google.com/search?q=subspace) that you are thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, *subspace* is not a real theory.**

Also, before you ask "could *subspace* be {extra dimensions, multiverse, baby / bubble universes, etc.}" consider that *subspace* is a science fiction term and it's off topic here to try to get into the head of authors and figure out what they meant.

Regarding whether or not {extra dimensions, multiverse, baby / bubble universes, etc.} exist, that would be for a different question.  Be warned though, most of that stuff is still too hypothetical / non-mainstream and probably off topic too.